# error when starting react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I work with React v15.6.1 and Yarn and I have tried to start react app from the terminal, but when I execute command "yarn start" throw an error and not run the app

**Log: yarn start**

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: watch /home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/public ENOSPC
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

so I tried to execute the command 'npm install' but not indicated others errors.

**Log: npm install**

```
multicomp@0.1.0 /home/navastud/atom-workspace/intervijs
├─┬ eslint@5.2.0
│ ├── chalk@2.4.1 
│ ├─┬ inquirer@5.2.0
│ │ └─┬ string-width@2.1.1
│ │   └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│ │     └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
│ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.12.0 
│ │ └── esprima@4.0.1  
│ ├─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│ │ └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
│ └─┬ table@4.0.3
│   ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ajv@6.5.2
│   └── chalk@2.4.1 
├─┬ eslint-config-equimper@2.2.2
│ ├─┬ babel-eslint@8.2.6
│ │ └─┬ @babel/code-frame@7.0.0-beta.44
│ │   └─┬ @babel/highlight@7.0.0-beta.44
│ │     └── chalk@2.4.1 
│ ├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@4.19.1
│ │ ├── chalk@2.4.1 
│ │ ├─┬ espree@3.5.4 
│ │ │ └─┬ acorn-jsx@3.0.1 
│ │ │   └── acorn@3.3.0 
│ │ ├── ignore@3.3.10 
│ │ ├─┬ inquirer@3.3.0
│ │ │ ├── chalk@2.4.1 
│ │ │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│ │ │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
│ │ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.12.0 
│ │ │ └── esprima@4.0.1 
│ │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│ │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
│ └─┬ eslint-plugin-class-property@1.1.0
│   └─┬ eslint@3.19.0
│     ├─┬ espree@3.5.4 
│     │ └─┬ acorn-jsx@3.0.1 
│     │   └── acorn@3.3.0 
│     ├── ignore@3.3.10 
│     └─┬ table@3.8.3
│       └─┬ string-width@2.1.1
│         └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│           └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@15.6.2
└─┬ react-scripts@1.1.4
├─┬ autoprefixer@7.1.6
│ └─┬ postcss@6.0.23
│   └── chalk@2.4.1 
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@4.10.0
│ ├── chalk@2.4.1 
│ ├── eslint-scope@3.7.3 
│ ├─┬ espree@3.5.4 
│ │ └─┬ acorn-jsx@3.0.1 
│ │   └── acorn@3.3.0 
│ ├── ignore@3.3.10 
│ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.12.0 
│ │ └── esprima@4.0.1 
│ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
└─┬ sw-precache-webpack-plugin@0.11.4
  └─┬ sw-precache@5.2.1
    └─┬ update-notifier@2.5.0
      ├─┬ boxen@1.3.0
      │ └── chalk@2.4.1 
      └── chalk@2.4.1 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /react-scripts /fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /webpack-dev-server/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-loader@1.9.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.8.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 4.x  but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || ^3 || ^4 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.4.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-d3-speedometer@0.3.2 requires a peer of react@^0.14.7 || ^16.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-svg-gauge@1.0.8 requires a peer of react@^16.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-svg-gauge@1.0.8 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.2.0 but none was installed.
```

why this happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried removing all dependencies and installing everything from scratch? `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`

Comment: thanks, worked correctly, but why this happens it?

Comment: Great! It can happen for a lot of different reasons, it's difficult to say what could have gone wrong in this particular case.

Comment: If re-installing node_modules worked, most likely it happened because there's a corrupt library.

Comment: how I can know if there's a corrupt library and repair it??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's difficult to say exactly why you have gotten this error, but if you remove the `node_modules` directory and reinstall every dependency it should work as expected.

```
rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

The following command can be used:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```